# django - "AppRegistryNotReady" message when I try to import csv file

Tags: python, django, csv

I want import csv file(`test.csv`) to database (`Store model`)

Here are my codes.

#### csv_upload.py

```
# encoding: utf-8

csv_filepathname = "PATH"
your_djangoproject_home = "PATH"

import sys, os
sys.path.append(your_djangoproject_home)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "lotterymap.settings"

from store.models import Store

import csv

with open(csv_filepathname) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        _, created = Store.objects.get_or_create(
            name=row[0],
            address=row[1],
        )
```

#### My path

```
lotterymap
  |> lotterymap
  |> store
  | csv_upload.py
  | test.csv
```

If I type `python csv_upload.py`, then `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from Django 1.8 you should [explicitly call](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage) `django.setup()`:

```
import django
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()
django.setup()
# Now you can use your models
from store.models import Store
```

Comment: I have a question why I should call `django.setup()`?